# Split text seperated by multiple characters using excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list in excel 2007 with text separated by 3 full stops. 
( i.e ASDA...TESCO...MORRISONS...CO-OP...)

Using the text to column tool I am unable to split using multiple characters (i.e ,,, or ...)
The separate to columns tool only seems to work for text separated by singular characters (i.e , or .)

How do I split text to columns which are separated by multiple characters?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to substitute the `...` by a character that's not in the file at all. Let's say that the file doesn't contain the character `|` (pipe), do a Find&Replace on:

Find: `...`

Replace: `|`

And then do a Text to column on the pipes.

[PS. Make sure the 'Match the entire cell contents' option is unchecked. If you don't see this, click <kbd>Options>></kbd> in the Find&Replace dialog box]